# Two-factor authentication with CAS

Tags: cas, two-factor-authentication, one-time-password, jasig

I’ve been asked to modify our CAS instance to have a second factor authentication

For us it’s easy to send an email or sms to the users.  So a custom OTP will be welcomed.

We’re not interested in a second instance of CAS.

Also we need the next behavior:

- Users can authenticate via personal certificate or password using the Corporate Network
- Users from Internet can authenticate via personal certificate or via password plus OTP

Now users from Internet can only be authenticated via personal certificate.  Passwords are for Corporate Network users only.  So the new feature will be the second factor OTP for Internet users

Is CAS able to do that?

Which CAS versions are ready to handle two factor authentication?

Comment: Now, I’m thinking in a Java filter and a custom Authentication Handler in order to get the two factor authentication.

The Java filter could take care of adding the second factor in the flow.

The custom authentication handler could delegate in BindLdapAuthenticationHandler and also ensure that the OTP have been properly set. 

Am I forgetting any implications?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CAS Radius Authentication Handler and forward authentication request via the RADIUS protocol to [privacyIDEA](http://privacyidea.org), which is a 2FA authentication system that supports many different authentication devices, ranging from key fobs, yubikey to Smartphone apps, SMS and email.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have to evaluate if it’s a good idea for my corporation to add a privacyIDEA.
It adds a little more complexity, and I’m not very sure how long will live our CAS server.
I was thinking more in configuring CAS to add a custom second factor, and implement the OTP

Comment: Is this work with RADIUS ? if please share some details?